# Form Table in VB 2010 Not Associated With Database

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know whether it is possible to create a table in VB 2010 that is not associated with a database. This table would be able to display text in its cells and have its row number change. If there is an object that allows for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is the same - called `DataTable`, you can create it manually:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
'...
dt.Columns.Add(...)
'...
dt.Rows.Add(...)
```